# Laravel 5.3 - Session store not set on request

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.3

I have a email verification system added in my Laravel app. I have used "jrean's" package for it.

Now I want to override the `getVerification()` function in `VerifiesUsers` trait. For which I have added a function with same name inside my RegisterController.

```
public function getVerification(Request $request, $token)

{    

 $this->validateRequest($request);

 try {
    UserVerification::process($request->input('email'), $token, $this->userTable());
 } catch (UserNotFoundException $e) {
    return redirect($this->redirectIfVerificationFails());
 } catch (UserIsVerifiedException $e) {
    return redirect($this->redirectIfVerified());
 } catch (TokenMismatchException $e) {
    return redirect($this->redirectIfVerificationFails());
 }

 $request->session()->flash('message', 'Email address has been successfully verified');
 return redirect($this->redirectAfterVerification());
}
```

But when my function gets called as per the verification call, I am getting the error "Session store not set on request." error. I am not sure what does it exactly mean and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the routes that are declared in the package are not put inside the `web` middleware.

To get around this you can add the routes from that package in to your `routes/web.php`. The routes are:

```
Route::get('email-verification/error', 'Auth\RegisterController@getVerificationError')->name('email-verification.error');
Route::get('email-verification/check/{token}', 'Auth\RegisterController@getVerification')->name('email-verification.check');
```

The your will just need to make sure that you in your `config/app.php` the `Jrean\UserVerification\UserVerificationServiceProvider::class,` line is above your `App` service providers (but underneath your `Illuminate` service providers).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks mate! You definitely saved my another weekend from getting screwed up. Never gave a thought to this. You definitely deserve a beer pint for this.